# Why I can't use npm packages in meteor project?

Tags: meteor, npm

I need to add a npm package in my meteor project (for example 'moment' package). First I typed this command : 
meteor npm install --save moment .
The package.json dependencies updated (moment package added), also in node_modules.
I want to use this package, so I add this line in the client side:

> const moment = require('moment');

I get this message in my browser console **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** in this line !!

Did I miss something ?

Comment: What about `import { moment } from 'moment';`?

Comment: I tried it and I get this message "Unexpected token import"... :(

Comment: Is it a new project or an upgraded project? What Meteor versions are involved? Can you post a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `meteor npm install meteor-node-stubs --save` for this to work. See [Using NPM Packages](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html) in the guide.

Comment: I did that but I still have the same message... :(

Comment: change your statement to `import moment from "moment";` and make sure you have installed the `ecmascript` package. `meteor add ecmascript`

Comment: I am installing ecmascript (0.4.6_1). I think the pb isn't there :(

Comment: Can I use **require** in client side ? or just in server side ?

Comment: With meteor-node-stubs you can use npm packages on the client too

Answer (score 0):

You can only use npm packages in meteor 1.3+. For any previous versions, you will need a wrapper package or you can use meteorhacks:npm.

Comment: I am using 1.4 now. so theoretically I can use npm packages but practically I can't in my project and that's make me mad !